# Spark giving column nameas value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

Spark is giving the column name as a value. I am trying to get data from Databricks

I am using the following code:

```
val query="SELECT * FROM test1"

val dataFrame = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", url)
  .option("user", user)
  .option("password", password)
  .option("dbtable", s"""( $query ) t""")
  .load()

dataFrame.show()
```

With that code, I am getting this output:

```
Output

+----+-----+-------+
|name|email|address|
+----+-----+-------+
|name|email|address|
|name|email|address|
+----+-----+-------+
```

This is what the table looks like in the DB:

| name | email | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| devendra | dev2311999@gmail.com | bhopal |

I am using DatabricksJDBC42.jar with spark version  3.3.1

As you can see, it is displaying the column names instead of the actual values. How can I make it display the actual name?

Comment: Hi, for debugging purposes, can you try to put only "test1" for "dbtable" option ? Also, a check if the database at the end of "url" option is the good one

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `query` inplace of `dtable` and check whether the data is getting fetched or not and then you can go back to `dtable` for your specific use case. I know that we can either use `query` or `dtable` but as there is not much context here I can just suggest you do a bottom-to-top approach.

```scala
val query="SELECT * FROM test1"

val dataFrame = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", url)
  .option("user", user)
  .option("password", password)
  .option("query", s"$query")
  .load()

dataFrame.show()
```

Comment: Rahul i have tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you also must configure `driver` option:

```
.option("driver", "com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver")
```

Comment: have you found any solution for this ? I am facing same issue